# Problems with modf() in a function

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to create a function that splits a value into two seperate values with the help of modf(). I want to be able to convert meters into feet and inches and I know how I'm supposed to do that but I can't seem to get it working with a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void metersToFeetAndInches(double meters, double feet, double inches, double feetTotal)
{
    feetTotal = meters * 3.281;
    inches = modf(feetTotal, &feet);
    inches = inches * 12.0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //With function

    double meters = 3.0;
    double feet;
    double inches;
    double total;

    metersToFeetAndInches(meters, feet, inches,  total);
    printf("%.1f meters is equal to %f feet and %.1f inches.\n", meters, feet, inches);

    //Without function

    double meters1 = 3.0;
    double feet1;
    double inches1;

    double total1 = meters1 * 3.281;

    inches1 = modf(total1, &feet1);

    inches1 = inches1 * 12.0;

    printf("The first number is %.0f and the second number is %.1f\n", feet1, inches1);

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result:

```
3.0 meters is equal to 0.000000 feet and 0.0 inches.
The first number is 9 and the second number is 10.1
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here? Because I can't figure it out.

Comment: Please google for call by reference. You only pass a value to your function but you need to pass the reference (pointer) in order allow a change of the parameter.

Comment: Note: On a separate issue: magic numbers.  The `3.281` is naked.  Better to use something like `const double FeetPerMeter = 1000.0/(12*25.4);` or `#define FeetPerMeter (1000.0/(12*25.4))` and `feetTotal = meters * FeetPerMeter;`.  1) It self-documents what code is doing and 2) More accurate than 3.281.

Answer (score 2):

Two issues: pass by reference and unit segmentation.

OP's first approach can be fixed by passing the address of `main()`'s `feet` and `inches`and round.

```
#define meter_per_foot (1000/(12*25.4))
#define inch_per_foot 12

void metersToFeetAndInches(double meters, double *feet, double *inches) {
   double feetTotal = meters * meter_per_foot;
   feetTotal = meters * 3.281;
   *inches = modf(feetTotal, feet) * inch_per_foot;
}

...

metersToFeetAndInches(meters, &feet, &inches);
```

But due to printing a rounded `inches` in `printf("The first number is %.0f and the second number is %.1f\n", feet1, inches1);` the output could be like "10 feet 12.0 inches".

Instead convert to the minimum unit of interest, in this case 0.1 inches.

```
void metersToFeetAndInches10(double meters, double *feet, double *inches) {
   double unit = meters * meter_per_foot;
   unit *= inch_per_foot * 10;
   unit = round(unit);

   *inches = modf(unit/(inch_per_foot * 10), feet) * (inch_per_foot * 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void metersToFeetAndInches(double *meters, double *feet, double *inches, double *feetTotal)
{
    *feetTotal = *meters * 3.281;
    *inches = modf(*feetTotal, feet);
    *inches = *inches * 12.0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //With function

    double meters = 3.0;
    double feet;
    double inches;
    double total;

    metersToFeetAndInches(&meters, &feet, &inches,  &total);
    printf("%.1f meters is equal to %f feet and %.1f inches.\n", meters, feet, inches);
}
```

Modifying something from a function dosen't modify the value of the variables in `main` .This is why you need to use pointers as they contain the address of the variables so that when you modify them from the function,the value of the variables in `main` also changes. The `&` before the variable name will give the address of it. This is called [Pass by Reference](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/Pass_by_reference).You were doing [Pass by Value](http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms:Pass_by_value).

Comment: Well, maybe without the reference for `meter`.

Comment: @Nemesis , You are right.But it doesn't matter as `meters` is never modified inside the function

Comment: Agreed. I just made the comment to emphasis the need for call by reference (for changing values) and call by value (for simple input).

Comment: Thanks, what's the reason to use a "*" before the variables?

Edit: Never mind saw that you explained it in the message below the code. Once again thanks!

Comment: @kemkoi ,Pointers contain the address of the variable.What you need is the value of it and hence,you have to dereference it to get the value stored in that address.The `*` is needed to get the value or in other words,to dereference the pointer